# Is storing an access token for a third party resource on user's browser secure?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, frontend

I am learning about different Oauth2 flows but it does not provide any guidelines on securely persisting different kinds of access tokens in different scenarios and I could not find relevant information on the topic by Google-fu.

I am wondering if is it safe to save access tokens in a secure frontend context like httpOnly cookie and optionally directly calling the api from the browser without proxying it through the application server?

It appears more secure to me because access tokens unlike passwords cannot be hashed, the means to recover all access tokens (if encrypted)  must exist on the server otherwise it would not be able to call the service on behalf of the user. So, were the application server compromised so would the access tokens of all users.

Am I missing some context here or is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you think about sharing your own access token with some users user agent (browser), then this solution is never secure. The user agent (browser) is something working totally on behalf of the user. The user, if he wants to, may have access to any kind of resource the user agent operates with. Sharing a token with the user agent is like sharing the token with the user himself.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean insecurity here. The user in this case is just accessing his/her own resources which they could just as easily manipulate themselves by logging into the third party app.

Comment: Does the token you are sending belong to the user or is this your own token that belongs to the application? If the token belongs to the application than I could e.g. read it, take it as my own and use it elsewhere and just let you pay the costs for the API calls. This is what I mean by insecure.

Comment: I meant the access token belonging to the user.

Comment: If it belongs to the user anyway, then send it to the user and let him call the API directly.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever method you choose, you need to ensure your **backend verifies the token** (e.g jwt).

You probably wouldn't need to verify a secure cookie because a secure cookie cannot be accessed/modified by the browser.

Comment: What if the access token is generated by a third party server? Is is safe to directly call the service without proxying through my app server?

Comment: the rule of security is, never trust anything from the client (e.g. browser). Even if you use service like Firebase, you need to validate the token on the backend with the authentication service. Of course, to cut down turn around time, you should also cache the validation.

Comment: We cannot validate the token because we do not generate it. It is validated by the party who generated it upon every request.

Comment: Then it's better yoube specific who is the third party provider? What kkind of token? Though, if it's a third party provider, there's always a way to validate token

Comment: Consider any third party provider such as Google. It generates access tokens for particular users **which it will verify for every request whether it comes from browser or our application server**.

Comment: If you are talking about Google Login, you will need to pass the tokens to the backend, verify the tokens, and issue your own token to maintain the session. You may want to look at something like google's Firebase Authentication

Comment: What do you mean by verifying the token? The jwt tokens are signed by Google's servers, not us we cannot validate them unless we have Google's private key.

Comment: may I confirm you are just using Google Login? If you are using Google Login only, you will still need backend to create your own authentication service. Please checkout Firebase Authentication

Comment: I am not using Google, I gave the example of Google as a third party resource provider. Of course, I might need authentication service of my own but that is orthogonal concern. Here I only asked whether is it safe to embed the access token generated by a third party client on frontend.

Comment: then you have your answer.